# Unable to perform maven release in StarTeam

Tags: svn, maven, maven-release-plugin, starteam

I am unable to perform Maven release in Starteam and get the following error.

**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project TestPrj: An error is occurred in the tag process: Exception while executing SCM command. This provider doesn't support tagging subsets of a directory**

The same command works in svn. Doesn't Starteam support tagging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug in the StarTeam provider. Try version 2.1 of `maven-release-plugin` and see if that works.

This error is thrown when you tried to tag something specific, rather than the whole repository. From [Maven SCM 1.4](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/scm/tags/maven-scm-1.4/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-provider-starteam/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/scm/provider/starteam/command/tag/StarteamTagCommand.java), in the 2.1 `maven-release-plugin`:

```
    if ( fileSet.getFiles().length != 0 )
    {
        throw new ScmException( "This provider doesn't support tagging subsets of a directory" );
    }
```

Later [it was changed](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/scm/trunk/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-provider-starteam/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/scm/provider/starteam/command/tag/StarteamTagCommand.java?r1=1056959&r2=1056958&pathrev=1056959) and the sense inverted:

```
     {
-        if ( fileSet.getFiles().length != 0 )
+        if ( fileSet.getFileList().isEmpty() )
         {
```

For the Subversion provider, [this was fixed](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/scm/trunk/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-providers-svn/maven-scm-provider-svnexe/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/scm/provider/svn/svnexe/command/tag/SvnTagCommand.java?r1=1057940&r2=1057939&pathrev=1057940):

```
-        if ( fileSet.getFileList().isEmpty() )
+        if ( !fileSet.getFileList().isEmpty() )
         {
```

It hasn't been fixed for StarTeam; if rolling back to 2.1 works, consider [opening an issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM).